# Selenium Firefox - Browser is under remote control

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am using `Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit)` with selenium. The code works fine, however I see an icon in Firefox saying `Browser is under remote control` and the URL is highlighted in orange as shown in below screen shot.

[image: Firefox Message]

Is there a way to disable this message in Firefox?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: You must change user-agent. Do you have tried it before?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't get that in the previous versions of firefox (version 45 or below). Its just an update and cannot be disabled. Even google chrome shows a message(chrome is autmated by a software).  or you could just use the previous versions of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related directly to selenium use,
But in case of getting stuck in "under remote control" after having launched firefox with a kind of:

```
firefox -marionette -foreground -no-remote -profile /path/to/existing/profile
```

It's because this way it toggles `marionette:true` in about:config,
Thanks to [Firefox Stuck in Remote Control Mode](https://www.jondelamotte.com/blog/firefox-stuck-in-remote-control-mode/) for pointing to this marionette config entry